# Determine the time complexity in the worst case of the given piece of code

Tags: complexity-theory

Determine the time complexity in the worst case. (show computations)

```
  int i = 1;
  int j = 4;
  while (i<(n*n)&& j<(n*n*n*n)){
    if (i%3 == 0) i+=3; 
    else i+=4;

    if (j%2 == 0) j*=4;
    else j*=2;          
 }
```

Comment: (If this *isn't* homework, it is still sufficiently close -- in any case, what have you tried? Was it just wrong or ..?)

Comment: can you tell us what you think the answer is and why? I don't mean to shoot you down, but you should try first.

Comment: Note that complexity is an upper-bound so you just need to do the "max" of effectively two *separate* loops/problems: the one with `i` and then the one with `j`. (This should be a start to work something out.)

Comment: i tried to solve it, (i) starts with (1) but it would stop when it equal or greater than (n^2) . (j) starts with 4 but it would stop when it become equal or bigger than (n^4) . that made me feel it's = O(n^4) . but then the increasing statements looked complicated so i wasn't sure how to figure it out

Comment: since you determine time complexity by assuming the worse case scenario, assume that i+=4 and j*=4 occurs every iteration.

Comment: There is no worst/best case here. The number of iterations depend solely on `n`.

Comment: @Bart What a shame. I think it is a very handy separation.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson But that can't be assumed because `i` and `j` are set initially and processed through pure functions. There is some precise rules for when it is `+3/+4` and some precise rules for when it is `*2/*4`, which is set that is *independent* of `n`. Only if it is shown that picking one or the other does *not* decrease the complexity can that simplification be used.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson (It can be shown that it doesn't change the growth, which is important, as C can be discarded. But this is different from always assuming one path is picked; however, that can be shown for `j` trivially as well.)

Comment: Yes, I think it is very important to point out that it doesn't matter what numbers are added ever.  You could add 2,000,000,000 every iteration and the complexity still stands because you are linearly approaching n^2.  O(n^2/2)=O(n^2/1,000,000,000)

Answer (score 1):

In worst case this is going to run in whichever ends soonest i reaching n^2 or j reaching n^4.  The variable i is increasing linearly and j is increasing exponentially each iteration.  j is just becoming a different power of 4 each iteration.

i will reach n^2 after n^2/3 iterations which is O(n^2).
j will reach n^4 after log_4 n^4 iterations (where log_4 is log base 4).

so the question is which is bigger n^2 or log(n^4) and the answer is a resounding n^2.

Therefore this algorithm is O(n^2)